# Why would a SQL query need to be so complicated like this feature allows?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am studying for SQL exam, and I came across this fact, regarding subqueries:

```
2. Main query and subquery can get data from different tables
```

When is a case when this feature would be useful? I find it difficult to imagine such a case.

Comment: That is why it is useful. It would be totally useless if you couldn't get data from different tables and join the results

Comment: This is the typical case. Sub queries back onto the same table are probably less common.

Comment: "Much to learn, you still have." - Yoda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Millions of situations call for finding information in different tables, it's the basis of relational data.  Here's an example:

Find the emergency contact information for all students who are in a chemistry class:

```
SELECT Emergency_Name, Emergency_Phone
FROM tbl_StudentInfo
WHERE StudentID IN (SELECT b.StudentID
                    FROM tbl_ClassEnroll b
                    WHERE Subject = 'Chemistry')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tableB)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of reasons why you have to get data from different tables, such as select sth from main query, which is based on subquery/subqueries from another tables. The usage is really huge.

- choose customers from main query which is based on regions and their values

  `SELECT * FROM customers 
  WHERE country IN(SELECT name FROM country WHERE name LIKE '%land%')`
- choose products from main query which is greater or lower than average incoming salary of customers and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like,

```
SELECT SUM(trans) as 'Transactions', branch.city as 'city' 
FROM account 
INNER JOIN branch 
ON branch.bID = account.bID
GROUP BY branch.city
HAVING SUM(account.trans) < 0;
```

This would for a company to identify which branch makes the most profit and which branch is making a loss, it would help identify if the company had to make changes to their marketing approach in certain regions, in theory allowing for the company to become more dynamic and reactive to changes in the economy at any give time.

Comment: Where's the sub query?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry there, HAVING SUM(account.trans) < 0; will identify problem locations.